# Why django gives me this get error while making my first poll apps

Tags: python, django, get

I was following this tutorial: "https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.0/intro/tutorial03/", and it was all good until this part, where I encountered this error.
[django error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk0U4.png)

mysite/urls

```js
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

mysite/polls/models

```js
import datetime

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

mysite/polls/urls

```js
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

mysite/polls/views

```js
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world, this is Hernán.")


def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

and at mysite/settings is all default, except I changed this

```js
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Belem'
```

I hope you guys can help me, thanks

Comment: You forgot to add a slash in the `polls` url.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add a slash in the `polls` url. It should be:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, how it was working just fine until now? I haven't touched that file in a while. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @HermanG: if you only used `path('')` in the `polls.urls`, then there is not much of a problem, since then it will just "strip" the trailing slash.